# Matching substrings SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column with big strings. I want to search through these strings and see if there are 4 consecutive upper case characters. Is there a way of doing this? I'm not too experienced in the substring methods of SQL.

Comment: What parts of the documentation have you read through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking for 4 chars inside a string is a classic [LIKE](http://LIKE) in most SQL dialects.

To force upper case, you need to coerce the collation too with the [COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) clause. The "CS" makes your column case sensitive

```
...
WHERE
   MyColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '%ABCD%'
```

Edit: for any 4 upper case characters

```
...
WHERE
   MyColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE '%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%'
```

Edit: with Latin1_General_BIN

Comment: I need it to check for any uppercase letters. Would I be able to use '%A-Z%' for that?

Comment: @Aeonstrife: updated answer. Please check my LIKE link for more examples of how to use it

Comment: @Erik: that would check one letter only. We need 4 consecutive.

Comment: @Aeonstrife: Please accept and/or upvote then please (arrows + tick on the left)

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is but it seems like it's returning as true for all of them even though it's not the case. The line I'm using is:

`[UpperCasePresent] = CASE WHEN LST.ListingDescription COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE '%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END` 

and it's returning 1 every time

Comment: After testing and editing the data, it seems like the statement is not obeying the uppercase command. Hello and HELLO both return 1 but hel and HEL return 0

Comment: @Aeonstrife: Use Latin1_General_BIN. I need to look into why CS isn't working (I'd normally use BIN anyway)

Comment: Yes gbn, I know it will only catch one character, it was a drive-by comment. :) @Aeon Maybe you could put the COLLATE clause on the string instead of the column? To see the collations available on your server, do `SELECT * FROM ::fn_helpcollation()`.

Comment: @gbn - Because the CS sort order is `aAbBcC...zZ` and all the lower case letters except `a` are in the range `A-Z`

Comment: @Martin nice catch, very logical, too. :)